# JavaのStringについて

Tags: java

プログラミング初心者です。

```
String name1 =“Japan”;
String name2 =“USA”;
String name3;
name3 = name1;
name1 = name2;
name2 = “UK”;
system.out.println(name1);
system.out.println(name2);
system.out.println(name3);
```

上記コードのアウトプットは

```
UK (name1 = name2 = UK と考えました)
UK
UK (name3 = name1 = name2 = UK と考えました)
```

と表示されると思っていましたが、
実際は、以下の通り表示されます。

```
USA
UK
Japan
```

なぜこのように表示されるかご教示頂けますと幸いです。
どうぞよろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

プログラミング言語の代入と、等値性の宣言を混同されているのでしょうか。

```
String name1 =“Japan”;
String name2 =“USA”;
String name3;
name3 = name1; //`name3`にはこの時点の`name1`の値である"Japan"が代入される
name1 = name2; //`name1`にはこの時点の`name2`の値である"USA"が代入される、`name3`には無関係
name2 = “UK”;  //`name2`にはこの時点で"UK"が代入される、`name1`や`name3`には無関係
```

1行目の代入で設定された`name3`の値が2行目の`name1 = name2;`で変わることはありません。数学記号の`=`を使っていますが、`name3 = name1;`という代入は、「この後ずっと`name3`と`name1`を同じ値にする」という意味ではなく、単に「その時点の`name1`の値を`name3`に代入するだけ」(以下同様)と言うのがわかればすぐにご理解いただけると思うのですが、いかがでしょうか?

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。等価(==)と代入(=)を混同していました。

Answer (score 1):

上記の説明、ちょっと違う気がするのですが、、、

例えば、

> name3 = name1;
>   これは、この時の name1 の値 "japan"が name3に代入されるのではなく、name3が指し示すオブジェクトが "japan" という(name1が指し示していた)オブジェクトになる事では?
>   同様に、
>   name1 = name2;
>   name1が指し示すオブジェクトが (この時、name2が指し示す) "USA"になり、
>   name2 = "UK";
>   name2 が指し示すのが、(新しく作られた) "UK" というオブジェクトになる。

文字で書くとちょっと分かりにくいかも知れません。

で注意が必要なのが、文字列の比較。 同じ文字列(を指し示す 変数)でも == の比較で一致と判定され無い事があります。
  name1 = "USA";
  name2 = "USA";
  (name1 == name2) ==> これは一致すると思われる。(同じオブジェクトを指している可能性大)
  name3 = "US";
  name2 = name3 + "A";
  (name1 == name2) ==> 一致しないと判定される。(筈。--> 違うと指摘あり、仕様確認が必要)

理由は、== が中の文字列で判定していないためで、他のオブジェクトでも同様。
string.equals メソッド等で判定する必要があります。

以上、参考までに。

Comment: 補足ありがとうございます。ただ、質問者さんの質問内容と誤解の内容は「代入」の意味そのものに関わるところですので、現在の学習レベルでは「参照」の込み入った話はかえって理解を妨げると考えて私の今の回答のような表記にしてあります。ちなみにあなたの例の`name1 == name2`については、「必ず`true`を返す」と言うのがJavaの言語仕様で決まっています。(文字列リテラルは必ずinternされる。)

Comment: 参照の件を無視すると後からの修正は難しくなると思っています。 代入とすると、その後の文字列編集で問題を起こすと考えました。なお、数字の場合との違いも書きたかったのですが、さすがに止めましたが。 文字列比較については、ちょっと自信が無かったので、検索して確認したつもりだったのですが、見る場所が違っていたでしょうか?

Comment: Javaの文字列は変更不可で、参照型であることで違いの出る方が珍しいですし、特に問題はないように思います。もちろん、将来のために参照型での問題についてどこかに書きとめた方がよかったかと迷っていたのですが、あなたに別回答の形で示していただいたので、それも必要なくなったと判断しています。ありがとうございました。

Comment: ん？ https://paiza.io/projects/dbhzko0B8nEY3sNtWUoLKw

Comment: @greentea さん、何のことだろうと思ったら、後半にも`name1 == name2`があったのですね。私のコメントの「あなたの例の`name1 == name2`について」は前半の`name1 == name2`のことです。不十分な指摘の仕方で混乱させてしまい失礼しました。